# MySQL REGEXP (problem with params order)

Tags: regex, mysql

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM (test) test_label WHERE REGEXP "AA(.*)BB" OR test_label REGEXP "BB(.*)AA"**
```

Database (string):

```
1. AA BB 100
2. AA BB 200
3. BB AA 300
4. BB CC 100
5. AA CC 300
```

This query returns rows: 1, 2 and 3.

How:

Combine this expression into one (but - i want it with one REGEXP but not with OR - if it is possible it must not take order of input vars and i don't must search for all possible combinations)

Now if query is "AA BB" i must find all possible cases - in this case it's only:

- AA(.*)BB|BB(.*)AA

but if query is "AA BB CC" it is a lot more cases.

Test cases:

1. query "AA BB" returns rows 1,2,3.
2. query "BB 300" return only row 3.
3. query "BB CC 100" return only row 4.
4. query "BB 100" return rows 1,4.

Answer (score 0):

```
AA(.*)BB|BB(.*)AA
```

should do, although I don't understand why you would want to capture the space between AA and BB, so `AA.*BB|BB.*AA` would work just as well.

If the number of possible strings increases, it depends on what you want to allow as valid matches. If you want "true" combinations, i. e. all three elements of a list like `AA, BB, CC` must be present exactly once, in any order, then MySQL (using a POSIX ERE engine and therefore not having backreferences implemented) leaves you no choice but to spell out all possible combinations:

```
AA.*BB.*CC|AA.*CC.*BB|BB.*AA.*CC|BB.*CC.*AA|CC.*AA.*BB|CC.*BB.*AA
```

and so on for more elements.

Comment: Thanks for answer - but i do not want to look for all possible combinations and this is the problem.

Comment: I don't understand. You wanted to combine the expressions `AA(.*)BB` and `BB(.*)AA` into one, didn't you?

Comment: Not really. I would like that the order of input parametrs did not matter. Now if user input in search box "AA BB" i must find all possible combinations (in this case it's only 2, but if user type "AA BB CC DD EE" - it's  much more). I don't know that is possible to build query with REGEX that order of typed parametrs doesn't matter.

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain more fully what you actually want? Are these strings `AA`..`EE` predefined? Is the number of strings predefined? Can strings occur several times in the same sequence, and if so, should the match fail then? You should provide a list of test cases, showing exactly what you want and don't want to match. Right now, your requirements are hazy.

Comment: OK, I think I understand and have edited my answer. Unfortunately, MySQL's regex engine forces you to spell out all possible combinations.