# Query with multiple LIKE with AND condition using REGEXP

Tags: mysql

I want to search the same field but in multiple values using REGEXP. 
Is it possible?

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  posts 
WHERE keyword LIKE '%ipad%' 
  AND keyword LIKE '%iphone%' 
  AND keyword LIKE '%nokia%' ;
```

this query is use for OR , i want to convert it to AND condition

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE keyword REGEXP 'ipad|iphone|nokia';
```

Comment: Not worth it. You would get more than 3 times slower query

Answer (score 0):

Can your `keyword` field contain multiple values (devices)? Like `ipad;iphone;nokia`?

If so, this is bad practice. It violates First Normal Form, and it's a symptom of bad table design. Still, the way you did it with multiple `LIKE` and `AND` clauses should work.

Converting this to REGEXP syntax is not easy in MySQL, and definitely not worth the trouble. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966999/mysql-regexp-problem-with-params-order) for more details.

Comment: its not working sir , i think u couldnot understand my question

Comment: If your `keyword` field has only one value per row, then what you're trying to do is impossible.

Comment: keyword field has multiple values or like hai text field.